# Recognize String has digits

Tags: java

This is my input verifier:

```
public class MyInputVerifier extends InputVerifier {

@Override
public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
    String text = ((JTextField) input).getText().trim()
    if (text.isEmpty() || text.length() == 0) return false;
    // How verifier that if text contains digit, return false?
    return true;
}
```

I need to recognize when `text` contains digit(s), it return false to me.

Is there any method Or i should use old way?(for loop)

Comment: You can validate it against a regular expression.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()`??

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What's your mean?

Comment: @Sajjad there is plenty of literature about regular expressions around.

Comment: Java has [`IsDigit()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/character_isdigit.htm) method.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, But that method need for loop!

Comment: @Sajjad - Yes, I posted such answer introducing `containsDidit()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way of checking if `text` contains a digit:

```
boolean containsADigit = text.matches(".*\\d.*");
```

If you want to check if all characters are digits you can still use regular expressions, or try parsing the string as an integer:

```
boolean isDigitsOnly = text.matches("\\d*");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using only very basic stuff:

```
public boolean containsDigit(String str) {

   int n = str.size();
   for(int i=1, i<n, ++i) {
       if(str.charAt(i).isDigit()) {return true;}      
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. It's obviously not a one-line solution, but does not use anything even remotely close to advanced stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a more faster way?

```
private boolean hasOnlyDigits(String str) {
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```